# AngularJS: Remove the directive of lower priority?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive which can remove `ng-disabled` programmically (e.g.: when current user has no permission for editing, remove `ng-disabled` and add a static `disabled` attribute directly.)

I read the [official doc about $compile](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-), it says I can specify `priority` option to decide the compilation order. The [source code of latest AngularJS 1.7.9](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.js) shows that the priority of `ngDisabled` is `100`, so I wrote this :

```js
app.directive('removeNgDisabled', function ($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 101,  // The priority of ngDisabled is 100
    compile: function ($el, $attrs) {
      const el = $el[0]
      el.removeAttribute('ng-disabled')  // ng-disabled should be removed before it is compiled... isn't it?!
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input ng-model="foo" ng-disabled="true" remove-ng-disabled=""/>
```

I don't know where do I get wrong, `ng-disabled` disappeared from DOM indeed, but `ng-disabled` still works...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It's not like it's a real protection because it runs on the client side. You can just control the `ngDisabled` directive from your controller

Comment: 1. Surely server-side also does permission checking...  2. The spec is just very complicated which every field has independent permission. There are hundreds of fields so I don't want to mix them with inputs' themselves validators.

Comment: 3. Besides deleting `ngDisabled`, some other behaviors are need to be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to remove the directives have already existed on an HTML element as soon as Angular start to `$compile` that element.

[The official document](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-) only says that:

> The `priority` is used to sort the directives before their `compile` functions get called.

but it seems not mean to you can do any thing before the sorting. That is to say, when the "higher-ordering" directive has been compiled, the lower-ordering directives had already been push in the execution queue (I guess, I didn't dig into the internal implementation.) and had become unable to be removed.

I didn't dig into the internal implementation of the mechanism of directive in AngularJS; but at least, in the official document, there's no way to "cancel" or "remove" existed directives. So the only way to achieve similar behavior is to implement a homebrewed `ng-disabled` by yourself.